# gitignore .tfvars but not .auto.tfvars

Tags: terraform, gitignore

I'm trying to avoid committing some Terraform vars while committing others. I was hoping something like the following in `gitignore` would work, but it doesn't.

```
*.tfvars
!.auto.tfvars
```

I've tried `.tfvars.json` but am struggling to get JSON to a TF map object to work properly and think a gitignore exception like `!.auto.tfvars` to be superior.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NM I need to make it

```
*.tfvars
!*.auto.tfvars
```

with the `*` before `.auto.tfvars`

Comment: Even though you answered your own question, you should mark this answer as accepted.